# Size of transitive commutative permutation group

Tags: group-theory

I do not see at all how to start the following exercise:

> Suppose $G$ is a commutative subgroup of $S_n$ such that for every $1\le a,b\le n$ there exists a $g\in G$ for which $g(a)=b$. Show that $G$ has size $n$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you've written.

Comment: This must be stated incorrectly (in addition to having fairly poor wording): there are commutative subgroups $G\le S_n$ such that there exist two integers $1\le a,b\le n$ and a $g\in G$ such that $g(a)=b$ that do *not* have order $n$. (In fact, this existence property is satisfied by every single subgroup of $S_n$.) Perhaps you mean *for all* $1\le a,b\le n$ there exists a $g\in G$ such that $g(a)=b$, i.e. you are stipulating $G$ is an abelian *transitive* permutation group?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: Every abelian group that acts transitively and faithfully on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ has order $n$?

Comment: anon: yes, sorry for the poor translation

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be an abelian subgroup of $S_n$ such that the standard action on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is transitive.

**Claim.** The map  $F\colon G\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $g\mapsto g(1)$ is a bijection.

*Proof.* By transitivity of the action, for $1\le i\le n$ there exists $g_i\in G$ such that $g_i(1)=i$. As $F(g_i)=i$, the map $F$ is surjective.
Let $g,h\in G$ be elements with $F(g)=F(h)$. Then $1$ is a fixed point of $g^{-1}h$. Let $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then $g_kg^{-1}hg_k^{-1}(k)=k$ so that by commutativity of $G$ also $g_kg_k^{-1}g^{-1}h(k)=k$, i.e. $g^{-1}h$ is the identity, $g=h$. We conclude that $F$ is injective. $_\square$

Comment: Thank you, so i can prove g↦g(i) for 1≤i≤n is a bijection so i have n bijection. Therefore i can conclude that the order of G is n?